# Django aggregate query across 3 models

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I have 3 models: `Event`,`Product` and `Ticket`.

Every `Event` can have multiple `Products` and every `Product` can have multiple `Tickets`. Now I want to calculate the total revenue for an event. I can easily use this line of code to calculate the total amount of revenue for 1 product like so:

```
Product.objects.annotate(
    revenue = ExpressionWrapper(Count('tickets')*   F('price'),output_field=DecimalField()),
)
```

However if I try to calculate the total revenue for all the products in the Event it does not work. These are my models:

```
class Event(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    amount = models.IntegerField()
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2)
    event = models.ForeignKey(Event,related_name='products')

class Ticket(models.Model):
    buyername = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    buyeremail = models.EmailField(max_length=254)
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product,related_name='tickets')
```

Answer (score 0):

This gives you a queryset of events with the added `revenue` field which is the sum of all the prices of the tickets related to each Event

```
from django.db.models import Sum
qs = Event.objects.annotate(revenue=Sum('products__price'))
```

Please refer to the official [Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/aggregation/#joins-and-aggregates) for further info